# How ANTLR decides whether terminals should be separated with whitespaces or not?

Tags: swift, antlr, antlr4, lexical-analysis, language-recognition

I'm writing lexical analyzer in Swift for Swift. I used ANTLR's grammar, but I faced with problem that I don't understand how ANTLR decides whether terminals should be separated with whitespaces.

Here's the grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/swift/Swift.g4

Assume we have casting in Swift. It can also operate with optional types (Int?, String?) and with non-optional types (Int, String). Here are valid examples: "as? Int", "as Int", "as?Int". Invalid examples: "asInt" (it isn't a cast). I've implemented logic, when terminals in grammar rules can be separated with 0 or more WS (whitespace) symbols. But with this logic "asInt" is matching a cast, because it contains "as" and a type "Int" and have 0 or more WS symbols. But it should be invalid.

Swift grammar contains these rules:

```
DOT     : '.' ;
LCURLY  : '{' ;
LPAREN  : '(' ;
LBRACK  : '[' ;
RCURLY  : '}' ;
RPAREN  : ')' ;
RBRACK  : ']' ;
COMMA   : ',' ;
COLON   : ':' ;
SEMI    : ';' ;
LT      : '<' ;
GT      : '>' ;
UNDERSCORE : '_' ;
BANG    : '!' ;
QUESTION: '?' ;
AT      : '@' ;
AND     : '&' ;
SUB     : '-' ;
EQUAL   : '=' ;
OR      : '|' ;
DIV     : '/' ;
ADD     : '+' ;
MUL     : '*' ;
MOD     : '%' ;
CARET   : '^' ;
TILDE   : '~' ;
```

It seems that all these terminals can be separated with other's with 0 WS symbols, and other terminals don't (e.g. "as" + Identifier).

Am I right? If I'm right, the problem is solved. But there may be more complex logic.

Now if I have rules

```
WS : [ \n\r\t\u000B\u000C\u0000]+
a : 'str1' b
b : 'str2' c
c : '+' d
d : 'str3'
```

I use them as if they were these rules:

```
WS : [ \n\r\t\u000B\u000C\u0000]+
a : WS? 'str1' WS? 'str2' WS? '+' WS? 'str3' WS?
```

And I suppose that they should be like these (I don't know and that is the question):

```
WS : [ \n\r\t\u000B\u000C\u0000]+
a: 'str1' WS 'str2' WS? '+' WS? 'str3'
```

(notice WS is not optional between 'str1' and 'str2')

So there's 2 questions:

1. Am I right?
2. What I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the ANTLR `WS` rule in your Swift grammar:

```
WS : [ \n\r\t\u000B\u000C\u0000]+               -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

The `-> channel(HIDDEN)` instruction tells the lexer to put these tokens on a separate channel, so the parser won't see them at all. You shouldn't litter your grammar with `WS` rules - it'd become unreadable.

ANTLR works in two steps: you have the lexer and the parser. The lexer produces the tokens, and the parser tries to figure out a concrete syntax tree from these tokens and the grammar.

The lexer in ANTLR works like this:

- Consume characters as long as they match any lexer rule.
- If several rules match the text you've consumed, use the first one which appears in the grammar
- Literal strings in the grammar (like `'as'`) are turned into implicit lexer rules (equivalent to `TOKEN_AS: 'as';` except the name will be just `'as'`). These end up *first* in the lexer rules list.

### Example 1

Let's see the consequences of these when lexing `as?Int` (with a space at the end):

- `a`... potentially matches `Identifier` and `'as'`
- `as`... potentially matches `Identifier` and `'as'`
- `as?` does not match any lexer rule

Therefore, you consume `as`, which will become a token. Now you have to decide which will be the token type. Both `Identifier` and `'as'` rules match. `'as'` is an implicit lexer rule, and considered to appear first in the grammar, therefore it takes precedence. The lexer emits a token with text `as` of type `'as'`.

Next token.

- `?`... potentially matches the `QUESTION` rule
- `?I` doesn't match any rule

Therefore, you consume `?` from the input and emit a token of type `QUESTION` with text `?`.

Next token.

- `I`... potentially matches `Identifier`
- `In`... potentially matches `Identifier`
- `Int`... potentially matches `Identifier`
- `Int` (followed by a space) does not match anything

Therefore, you consume `Int` from the input and emit a token of type `Identifier` with text `Int`.

Next token.

- You have a space there, it matches the `WS` rule.

You consume that space, and emit a `WS` token on the `HIDDEN` channel. The parser won't see this.

### Example 2

Now let's see how `asInt` is tokenized.

- `a`... potentially matches `Identifier` and `'as'`
- `as`... potentially matches `Identifier` and `'as'`
- `asI`... potentially matches `Identifier`
- `asIn`... potentially matches `Identifier`
- `asInt`... potentially matches `Identifier`
- `asInt` followed by a space doesn't match any lexer rule.

Therefore, you consume `asInt` from the input stream, and emit an `Identifier` token with text `asInt`.

### The parser

The parser stage is *only* interested in the token types it gets. It does *not* care about what text they contain. Tokens outside the default channel are ignored, which means the following inputs:

- `as?Int` - tokens: `'as'` `QUESTION` `Identifier`
- `as? Int` - tokens: `'as'` `QUESTION` `WS` `Identifier`
- `as ? Int` - tokens: `'as'` `WS` `QUESTION` `WS` `Identifier`

Will all result in the parser seeing the following token types: `'as'` `QUESTION` `Identifier`, as `WS` is on a separate channel.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I thought that lexer and parser rules are working simultaneously while creating tree of tokens.

Comment: Nope, they're separate stages of parsing - which makes the concept pretty easy to grasp while playing nicely with most languages. But parsing languages which need information from the parser in the lexer is made difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me to write my tool. Here's output: http://pastebin.com/xvFWnhFC I am so happy.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad I could help :)